# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 2

Tags: java, исключения

Собственно при удалении многих строк из таблицы выскакивает данное исключение. А бывает, что не выскакивает. Я новичок и еще не понимаю как обрабатывать данные исключения. Полный лог исключения и добавляю код удаления:

```
for (int i=0; i<table.getSelectedRows().length;i++){
    for (int u=0; u<list.size(); u++){  

       if (table.getSelectedRows()[i] == list.get(u).getRowNum()){             
           list.remove(u);                                  
           u--;                                 
       }                        
    }
}
table.setModel(model.table(list));

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 2
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Предположу, что вы пробегаетесь в цикле с начала в конец, удаляя из середины...индекс смещается...и указатель прилетает за границу в итоге...........а вообще без подробного описания того, что вы делаете, с чем, и когда и без приведения кода - сложно что-либо сказать

Comment: Скорее всего, удаляете столбцы не в EDT.

Comment: не надо такое исключение обрабатывать, надо исправлять ошибку, которая его вызывает.

Comment: Добавил кусок кода где я удаляю из массива выбранные строки таблицы и потом заново пихаю новый массив в модель таблицы. А что такое EDT? В инете полазил и ничего толкового не нашел. И забыл написать, что все необходимые строки из  таблицы удаляется а потом вылетает это исключение

Comment: Как этот код вызывается, и что делает `table.setModel(model.table(list));`?

Answer (score 1):

```
   for (int u=0; u<list.size(); u++){  

   if (table.getSelectedRows()[i] == list.get(u).getRowNum()){             
       list.remove(u);                                  
       u--;     // так делать не надо и все будет хорошо                            
   }
```

допустим  list.size() = 10, а когда выполняется условие u уменьшается на 1 и в конечном итоге цикл

```
   for (int u=0; u<list.size(); u++)
```

отрабатывает не 10 раз а 11 или больше и обращается к не существующему значению

Comment: Да, u-- было лишним оно так же удаляет, но ошибка не исчезла-(

Comment: Тогда ставьте  brakepoint и включайте дэбаг меню в ide, ну и  пошагово смотрите что и как у Вас меняется